# R Insert wrong year in class date

Tags: r, date

I need to insert this row into my dataframe:

```
new_row<-c("015-06-17","1+-07-24",0,1,">=10")
```

How can i put this wrong dates in the columns BirthDate and MarriageDate who are in class Date?

Existing dataframe:

```
BirthDate        MarriageDate      Sons        Daugther      Time     

  1952-10-05       1980-11-03        1              0           <10
  1980-06-14       2002-05-20        0              2           >=10
```

Expected dataframe:

```
BirthDate        MarriageDate      Sons        Daugther      Time     

  1952-10-05       1980-11-03        1              0           <10
  1980-06-14       2002-05-20        0              2           >=10
  015-06-17         1+-07-24         0              1           >=10
```

I need to put them in the dataframe for correct them after insert.

Comment: I would like to do it but i don't see it.

Comment: ok i did it. thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear about the column types in 'df1'.  Assuming that all are 'character', then

```
rbind(df1, as.list(new_row))
```

Or if the 'Sons' and 'Daughther' are `numeric`, then we have to change the `vector` elements to respective classes.

```
lst <- lapply(new_row, function(x) { 
              x1 <- type.convert(x)
              if(is.factor(x1)) as.character(x1) else x1})

df2 <- rbind(df1, lst)
df2
#   BirthDate MarriageDate Sons Daugther Time
#1 1952-10-05   1980-11-03    1        0  <10
#2 1980-06-14   2002-05-20    0        2 >=10
#3  015-06-17     1+-07-24    0        1 >=10

str(df2)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
#$ BirthDate   : chr  "1952-10-05" "1980-06-14" "015-06-17"
#$ MarriageDate: chr  "1980-11-03" "2002-05-20" "1+-07-24"
#$ Sons        : int  1 0 0
#$ Daugther    : int  0 2 1
#$ Time        : chr  "<10" ">=10" ">=10"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but after trying, R response is  : Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Comment: @E.bl  If the 'BirthDate' and 'MarriageDate' are in `Date` class,convert them to `character` i.e. `df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.character)` as the 3rd row is not in the correct 'Date' format.

Comment: I tried this but the R response is now :  Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "lunch") : invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @E.bl It is also not good to use `factor` class.  `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x)`

Comment: I converted with  df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.character) then i did new_row<-c("015-06-17","1+-07-24",0,1,">=10") and df1<-rbind(df1,new_row)

Comment: @E.bl   Okay, what is the new problem.  If you look at my post, I used `rbind(df1, as.list(new_row))`